# Mark a place on Google Map and embed widget

Tags: html, google-maps, embed

http://snag.gy/mHDah.jpg

Please look at the above picture.
I want to add a place to the map and export embed html widget to my web site.
But the problem is a place is not there. (Not body added that place to Google Map).
I want to mark that place with a red point in a embed map. (Please look at the below snapshot)
http://snag.gy/7DFm3.jpg

 Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/) (Beta) is a tool which allows you to design and save your own custom maps. In order to make use of it, you'll need to have a Google account and be logged in.

> For example, have you tried to embed a newer Google map into a web
>   page? The reliable old "link" button is nowhere to be found!

A simple example is [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-embedding-new-google-maps--webdesign-15366)

Answer (score 1):

Those pins are called markers in the gmaps API.

This example does what you want: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

You can use normal Google maps to find out the coordinates for your place by right-clicking on it and choosing "what's here" (works in chrome and safari at least).